# WPF full screen on maximize

Tags: c#, wpf, fullscreen

I basically want to have my WPF window to go in full screen mode, when F11 is pressed or the maximize button in the right top corner of the window is pressed.

While the following works like a charm for pressing F11:

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.F11)
    {
        WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
        WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
        ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
    }
}
```

This will still displays the Windows taskbar (tested with Windows 7):

```
protected override void OnStateChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    if (WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
    {
        WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
        WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
        ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
    }
    base.OnStateChanged(e);
}
```

What am I missing here? Or can I do it even more elegant?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

WPF seems to be making the decision about whether to go full-screen or respect the taskbar based on the WindowStyle at the time of maximisation.  So a kludgy but effective solution is to switch the window back to non-maximised, set the WindowStyle, and then set the window back to maximised again:

```
private bool _inStateChange;

protected override void OnStateChanged(EventArgs e)
{
  if (WindowState == WindowState.Maximized && !_inStateChange)
  {
    _inStateChange = true;
    WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
    WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
    WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
    ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
    _inStateChange = false;
  }
  base.OnStateChanged(e);
}
```

Although the code is obviously ugly, the transition to Normal and then back to Maximized doesn't seem to make the user experience any worse.  On my display, I noticed flicker with both the F11 code and the kludge maximise, but not noticeably worse on the kludge maximise.  But your mileage may vary!

Comment: *knock knock* - Who's there?  - A semaphore from '70. Nice one though, it works. +1

Comment: This one works just fine. Even it's ugly, it feels still better then implementing `WindowInteropHelper` or some dll imports for something basic like fullscreen. I have to think about it, generally nice idea!

Comment: In fact this creates an ugly visible effect in Window XP, because both WindowState changes have a visual representation in Windows XP, which is a blue title-bar going up and down, giving a drunk window appeal with this technique.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
Topmost="True" and WindowState="Maximized"
```

you can see your window will cover all screen and hide all with windows taskbar

Comment: Worked better than any of the others on Windows 10!  (Anniversary update)

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the [Window.Topmost property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.topmost.aspx).

**Edit**

Check this blog post [Maximizing window (with WindowStyle=None) considering Taskbar](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2006/08/01/684535.aspx)

Comment: I tried `Topmost = true;` and it will not change the behaviour.

Comment: Stupid question. How can I check if my taskbar is set to "top most". As I said, it works fine (with and without `Topmost`) pressing F11.

Comment: Good question, seems you can't change that in windows 7. I'll do some more testing and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks, I'd really appreciate that. This behaviour drives me crazy ;)

Comment: That doesn't work for me -- bizarrely, it clips *part* of the taskbar but not the whole thing (Server 2008 with Aero theme).

Comment: @itowlson: That's exactly what I have with Windows 7 too. Also Aero theme, if that does have any importance.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution that worked for me:

> You can set the MaxHeight property of that window to
>   SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight using the constructor.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.MaxHeight = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight;
}
```

**Warning:** This might not work on extended desktop.

*Source:* [Maximize window with WindowState Problem (application will hide windows taskbar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890472/wpf-maximize-window-with-windowstate-problem-application-will-hide-windows-ta)

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to be using [WindowChrome](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.windowchrome(v=vs.110).aspx) to create a custom chrome experience, you'll need to set the [GlassFrameThickness](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.windowchrome.glassframethickness(v=vs.110).aspx) to something other than 0 (at least that was the last thing I needed to do to get the TaskBar to be hidden behind the window). That is in addition to the steps provided in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, minimizing and maximizing will make the fullscreen size to be a little bit bigger than the screen, so the alternative I found is to temporarily set the Visibility to Collapsed then back to Visible afterwards to force redraw.

```
Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is still someone that need a smooth full screen of course tested only on windows 10! In windows 10 minimized do less flickering if you maintain this code order!

```
    public bool IsFullscreen = false;
    public WindowState lastWindowState;
    private void player_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsFullscreen)
        {
            this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow;
            this.WindowState = lastWindowState;
            IsFullscreen = false;

        }
        else
        {
            lastWindowState = this.WindowState;

            this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
            if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
                this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
            this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
            IsFullscreen = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, works great on Windows XP and Windows 7 as well.

Comment: A problem with this answer is that it uses MouseDoubleClick event while the question ask how to change the behavior of Maximize button. While this will work, it would be better if the event used in this example changed so that it will address the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the taskbar if you import user32.dll...

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int FindWindow(string className, string windowText);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int ShowWindow(int hwnd, int command);

private const int SW_HIDE = 0;
private const int SW_SHOW = 1;
```

Usage:

```
int hwnd = FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd","");
ShowWindow(hwnd,SW_HIDE);
```

Comment: You just destroyed my taskbar!

Comment: Thanks kzen! Anyhow, this fells not very WPF like to me. But it could be an option.

Comment: And it actually just removed all my icons in the taskbar, it didn't remove the taskbar itself.

Answer (score 0):

I have found easy way to achieve fullscreen in WPF:

```
    private double LastHeight, LastWidth;
    private System.Windows.WindowState LastState;

    private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.F11)
        {
            if (WindowStyle != WindowStyle.None)
            {
                LastHeight = Height;
                LastWidth = Width;
                LastState = WindowState;

                Topmost = true;
                Width = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
                Height = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
                Top = 0;
                Left = 0;
                WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;
                WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
                ResizeMode = System.Windows.ResizeMode.NoResize;
            }
            else
            {
                WindowStyle = WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow;
                WindowState = LastState; ;
                ResizeMode = ResizeMode.CanResizeWithGrip;
                Topmost = false;
                Width = LastWidth;
                Height = LastHeight;
            }
        }
    }
```

This works good in Windows 7 with fixed Taskbar.

Comment: This way does not work when you are running the program on a dual screen machine because the program is always maximized on the left screen.