# Start windows 8.1 Store App in Windows 10 in full screen

Tags: c#, windows

Is it possible to force a Windows 8.1 Store App start in full screen on Windows 10 as it did on Windows 8? I tried it for days but I can't find a solution.

Comment: as said here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30936104/how-to-maximise-a-windows-10-universal-applications-window-to-full-screen-when

Comment: It works for Universal Apps, but not for a Windows 8.1 App :-/
Maybe I should try to convert my App to an Universal App.

Answer (score -1):

I guess, you can use `WindowState="Maximized"`.

Here is the example of the code:

```
<Window x:Class="HTA.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize"  
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized">
```

You can find more in similar question:

[WPF full screen on maximize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939219/wpf-full-sreen-on-maximize).

Comment: Many thanks for your fast help. But my solution is not of type Classic Windows WPF Application. It is a Windows 8.1 Store App. So my main windows is not of type "Window", it is of type "Page".

Answer (score -1):

If you create **universal window application**, use this code:

```
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;

namespace yourNameSpace
{
    sealed partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.FullScreen;
        }
    }
}
```

Look at [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.preferredlaunchwindowingmode.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) for detail information about **ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode**.